# Firestore Streambuilder as Future Widget

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have simple example where I want to read something from Cloud Firestore.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Test",
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: readFromFirestore()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget readFromFirestore() {
  StreamBuilder(
      stream:
          Firestore.instance.collection('users').document('test').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text("Loading...");
        }
        var userDocument = snapshot.data;
        return Text(userDocument["name"]);
      });
}
```

I want to make seperate firebase functions like read, write, update and so on... And I think they should be `Future`. How can I make this function below as Future?

```
Future <Widget> readFromFirestore()
```

This does not work though... I mean I cannot use it in `Center( )` above;

Comment: Did you look into [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)?

Comment: Without a return statement in front of your stream builder declaration, no widget actually gets returned from that function.